# Openpyxl: removing duplicates from one column while adding two integers together on another column

Tags: python, openpyxl

In the excel file there are many duplicates but i can't figure out how to get rid of them but since there are different total's on the duplicates i would like to know how to add the total together. This would be great help if you guys can figure it out

Example:

```
    Name Total 
    Bob   $680
    Selina $300
    Bob    $240
```

Expected

```
    Name Total 
    Bob $920
    Selina $300
```

It's like the example i need to get rid of the duplicates while adding the totals together

The code i used:

```
    import csv
    from openpyxl import load_workbook
    myList=[]
  mySheet = load_workbook('C:/Users/Shay/Documents/SampleData/SampleData(1).xlsm', data_only=True)                  
    mySheet = mySheet.active

 def listCreator(sheet):
     for r in range (1, 44):
         tempList = []
         if int(sheet.cell(row=r, column=6).value) >= 500:
            tempList.append(sheet.cell(row=r, column=2).value)
            tempList.append(sheet.cell(row=r, column=6).value)
            myList.append(tempList)
         print(myList)

      listCreator(mySheet)
      print("Your valued customers are...")
      for i in range(0,13):
           print(myList[i][0])
```

This is my first time posting, if you need me to clear anything up just ask

Comment: it is not clear which field is duplicated. can you please re-phrase your question?

Comment: I would recommend you look at loading the worksheet into Pandas, remove duplicates there and then load the results into an Excel sheet.

Comment: This is similar the same, read the Answer from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42482647/openpyxl-python-column-of-keys-column-of-values-how-to-add-up-the-values/42515799#42515799